# How do you get the count of posts in an archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I have a custom posts archive page of the type `archive-my_custom_post_type.php` and I am using the "standard" loop which consists of the ever-so famous

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        ...
    <?php endwhile;  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which seems to use global variables.

How would I go about getting the total amount of posts for this page? I need it to calculate the width of the columns I'm going to display these things in.

---

**Well, I found the answer:**

---

After some tedious inspection on the `$GLOBALS` variable in PHP, I found out you can get a reference to the `WP_Query` that was used to generate the page with `$wp_the_query`. And, lo and behold, you can get the amount of posts using this handy trick:

```
$countPosts = $wp_the_query->post_count;
```

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem I had!

Comment: You can put your answer in the answer box below your question and also mark this question as solved :)

Comment: Next time look at [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) it's far from perfect, but sometimes it's helpful :)

Answer (score 18):

As stated in the edit:

```
$count = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post_count;
```

Another option would be to use

```
$count = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts
```